# Unable to update database in MySQL, Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, sql-update

I am new to SQL and databases. Kindly answer my question in basic language.
I am unable to update a database value that contains only one table and one column. It consists of a role value (INT type) which I need to select the user's role. Here is the code:

```
else if (check==13)//failing to update
{
    try
    {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement s=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet pass=s.executeQuery("Select * from role");
        PreparedStatement ps;
        int up=cval;// cval is a int value from outside the else if block
        if ((up<0)||(up>3))
            System.out.println("Role doesn't exist");
        else {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("Update role set roleid="+up);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        while (pass.next())
            role=pass.getInt("roleid");
        if (role==up)
            System.out.println("Role changed successfully\n");
        else
            System.out.println("Role change unsuccessful\n");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Connection failed");
    }
}
```

Every time I check the value it is not updated. However, if I again execute this block of code it updates. There is no problem with the connection because I did other things to my database too.

Answer (score 1):

You obtain the ResultSet `pass` before you update the table, so it contains the old values.

Move this line:

```
ResultSet pass=s.executeQuery("Select * from role");
```

after you update the table.

Comment: Thanks very much my code is working properly now Thank you very much❤️❤️❤️

Comment: @Cap fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark after 5 mins or so.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps=connection.prepareStatement("Update role set roleid=?");
ps.setInt(1,up);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

prepareStatement code was wrong